# CoreData NSObjectInaccessibleException

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have the following flow in my application:
my first screen is a `UITableView` backed by a `NSFetchedResultController` and a background thread that refreshes my list.
the `NSManagedObject` for my table cells is called `DataItem` when i click on a cell i push another `viewcontroller` that displays more details about `DataItem` BUT if the background thread refreshes the list while i am pushing the `detailsviewcontroller` and during this update process i need to remove `DataItem` object it will cause the object to be invalidated so in my `detailsviewcontroller` when i try to access an attribute in `DataItem` will raise `NSObjectInaccessibleException`: "Core data could not fulfill a fault for ...."

What would be the best approach for this situation ? Instead of passing `DataItem` object to `detailsviewcontroller` should i just pass the necessary attributes from `DataItem`, or is there a workaround for this kind of situations?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/08/safely-fetching-nsmanagedobject-by-uri.html

In the section titled 'Safely getting the object back', Matt Gallagher describes a method for fetching a managed object using its URI. So in your case, instead of passing `DataItem` instance to the detail view controller, pass its URI. When the details view controller loads its view, try to fetch the object from that URI - using the method suggested in the article. If the object is not available anymore, you will get a `nil` value in return.

I haven't personally tried that code sample, so I'm not sure how it works. I hope it puts you on a path for a solution...

Comment: I don't think that this solution helps me too much because i need to protect myself against object deletion. I still need to delete the objects to keep my list accurate, but i can't make the user wait for me to make sure that the list is accurate.

Comment: The solution i found for now is to pass the necesary values from DataItem to my DetailsViewController and not the NSManagedObjectModel which can be invalidated at a later time.

Comment: @Mihai - but if your object is deleted by a background update, wouldn't you want to tell that to the user, instead of showing them a `DataItem` that doesn't exist anymore? It's your choice, but with my suggestion the fetch returns a `nil` instead of throwing an exception, so you are protected... all you need to do is have your `DetailViewController` show a user friendly message e.g. "Data item not available" whenever `nil` is returned by the fetch...